# Installation error with lubuntu on vmware Workstation 15 from iso file

Tags: boot, partitioning, lubuntu, vmware

So I am trying to setup Lubuntu on my vmware workstation 15 using an iso boot image using the 22.04.3 LTS download from https://lubuntu.me/downloads/
Creating the virtual machine works fine and I get to boot it from the iso file. The only problem is that I encounter this error when I try to run the dekstop Lubuntu installer in the virtual machine:

Error:

The installer failed to create a partition table on VMware Virtual S.

Details:
Create a new partition table (type: msdos) on '/dev/sda'

Job: Create new partition table on device '/dev/sda'

Command: sfdisk --wipe=always /dev/sda

The vm seems to be working fine and I manage to install vscode and anaconda3 on it, but when I restart the vm, everything is gone. Each time I reboot I am sent to the grub screen with the option "Try or Install Lubuntu". I assume this means that my OS is reinstalled everytime I reboot deleting existing files or running in Live mode. I assume this gets fixed once I get the installer to run, but I am not sure how to do this with the given error.

Edit VM specs:
So the VM is created with 100GB disk space and 12 GB RAM (My computer has closer to 30 available). It is registered as Guest operation system: Linux with Version Ubuntu 64-bit. The virtual disk is split into multiple files. 2 CPU cores used on vm out of 4

In the instalation I select Erase disk with swap to file option.  The selected storage device is /dev/sda

Comment: Did you read the release notes?  It will send you to this page (https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/calamares-rare-failure-to-create-partition-mkfs-errors/2774) on errors like what you experienced. Your returning to "Try or Install" is because you failed to remove the installation media on your VM.  Did you allocate sufficient space etc?  (*you gave no specifics on your VM*)

Comment: Your usage (specifically the *Erase disk and install*) doesn't match what I described in my prior link, but I'd still suggest you follow my *workaround*.  ie. I'd reboot your *live* media and not start the installer, but create your partitions BEFORE you start the installer, and just tell the installer what partition layout to use (*by selecting the partitions and telling the installer /sda2 for example is your / etc*).  If you have issues creating partitions in *KDE Partition Manager*, I'll suggest rebooting & then install `gparted` and use that instead of *KDE Partition Manager*